SDL2 test program doesn't seem to run and doesn't produce any error message
I would like to use the SDL2 library for capturing gamepad input so I put together a simple test program, but it doesn't do anything, no error message, no build errors, nothing:
program output
The source code is the following:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h> //for sleep
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>


#include "SDL.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* SDL test */
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER) <0)
    {
        perror("Failed to initialize SDL2 library\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    else printf("SDL2 initialized\n");

    printf("Test message");

    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I used VScode and CMake, the CMakeLists.txt file looks like the following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30.1)
project(sandbox_project VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C)


add_executable(sandbox_project WIN32 ${SOURCES})

# define the source files for the project
target_sources(sandbox_project PRIVATE 
    src/sandbox_main.c
    src/ring_buffer/ring_buff.h
    src/ring_buffer/ring_buff.c
)

# add the path of the cmake configuration files
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Everyngineering/programming/general_c_cpp/libraries/SDL2-devel-2.30.7-mingw/SDL2-2.30.7/cmake")
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)


# include directories
target_include_directories(sandbox_project
    PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR}/src
    PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR}/src/ring_buffer
    PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# include libraries
target_link_libraries(sandbox_project PRIVATE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})


# specify C standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# specifying the executable output
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/)

The SDL2 library was not built by me from the source I've downloaded the developer library with the precomplied files.
Many similar posts suggested that I should copy the SDL2.dll next to the executable which I did, nothing happened. Here is the project structure:
enter image description here
Can somebody point me to the right direction to solve this issue?

Have you tried disabling your antivirus? Also if its SDL.dll it may depend on having msvc runtime dlls.

Have you tried running your program line by line in a debugger to see at which point your program stops behaving as intended? Or is the problem that if you set a breakpoint at the start of main that this breakpoint does not get triggered?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

So it turned out that the simple printf is not going to work when SDL2 is running, that's why I can't see anything from the console.

Did you fflush(stdout); after doing the printf? If not, then the output may not be visible, if for example abort is called, which does not flush the buffers.

Is the printf statement that you are referring to the one in your posted code? Or did you insert another printf statement before the function call to SDL_Init?

Sorry for the late reply so I tested printf before the initialization and the fflush as well, neither of them works.
